# Error when Appending String with Record Set entry from Sqlite

Tags: c, string, sqlite, concatenation

I need to append a string with sqlite record set column entry, I use this

```
char a[16]=(unsigned char *)"Name: "+(unsigned char *)rs.recordset[0][1];
```

But I keep getting this error.

> error: invalid operands to binary `+`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the `+` sign does not concatenate a string.

As per the `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.6, *Additive operators*

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>   pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type.[..]

so, the `+` does not concatenate two *strings*.

You need to use [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) to join two *strings.*

Something like

```
char a[16] = {0};
strcat(a, "name");
strcat(a, rs.recordset[0][1] );
```

should do the job for you, provided, the length of `a` is sufficient to hold the final output (concatenated string) properly.

Comment: I wish it was easier like in c# or Java :) BTW i have edited your answer to fix an error.

Answer (score -2):

@ sourav, you need to copy "name",

```
    char a[16]=0;
    strcpy(a,"name");
    strcat(a, rs.recordset[0][1]);
```

Comment: This is an attempt to reply to [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35519589/1364007) and isn't an answer in its own right.

Comment: This is not an answer. As with your previour comment-as-answer, submitting a non-answer isn't appropiate to get around the rep limit for comments. Take a read of the [answer] and [help] please.